# C# Windows Phone 7 LiveConnect auto acces permissions

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, permissions

I use Microsoft Interactive SDK for login to Windows Live. The loggins works correctly, keeps in if the user has logged. But the permissions have to be access at all running of program...

How can I do that the program accesses permissions after first run?

Comment: your question is a little vague, do you mean User Data? Permissions from File Properties? please expand a little more

Comment: Hi!
I needed wl.offline_access for Windows Live sign in:)